# Swift optionals and their instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, option-type

I'm new to Swift. I'll explain what I'm trying to do in Java terms and hopefully someone can help me understand.

I want a class scoped array that is instantiated/set in viewDidLoad of a view controller. It sounds simple enough, but this is what I had to do to get it to work. Could someone explain to me why the _dictionary must be instantiated as an empty array and why I need to use as? when unpacking dictionary even though the componentsSeparatedByString function returns an array? Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    var _dictionary : [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
       let path = bundle.pathForResource(“TextFile”, ofType: "txt")
       var err: NSError?
       let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)
       if let dictionary = dico?.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as? [String]
       {
          _dictionary = dictionary
       }
       else
       {
          println("Error reading dictionary")
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_dictionary` must be given an initial value because *all* instance properties must be given an initial value. That is a Swift safety feature to make sure that all instances are well-formed at birth. You could have done this by initializing `_dictionary` in an actual initializer, but you didn't. You chose to give it its first "real" value in `viewDidLoad` which is much later. Therefore you have forced yourself to supply a "fake" initial value until such time as `viewDidLoad` comes along and gives you a "real" initial value.

I don't understand your other question because I don't know what "unpacking dictionary" means. But perhaps you are referring to the rest of the stuff in this code. I'll talk you through it.

- `dico` is an Optional wrapping a String. It is an Optional because the `contentsOfFile:` initializer of String returns an Optional - it is a *failable* initializer. That is because there might be no such file, or that file might not have that encoding, in which case the initializer needs to return nil.
- So now `dico` is an Optional wrapping a String that must be unwrapped - or nil. So you do unwrap it as `dico?` in the next line. `dico?` is a String at that point, assuming that `dico` was not nil.
- Then you call `componentsSeparatedByString`. It returns an array of `AnyObject`. So you have chosen to cast it down to an array of `String` using `as?`. I don't know why you chose to use `as?` since you know it will be an array of `String` if we get to this point - personally, I would have used `as`. But in any case, `as?` always returns an Optional! So you unwrap *that*, optionally, by using an `if let` conditional binding.

The irony throughout is that `_dictionary` is not and never was or will be a dictionary - it is an array. Your name for this (and for `dictionary`) is very poorly chosen! `dico` is a String, and `dictionary` and `_dictionary` are arrays. There is not a dictionary in sight.

Assuming we keep your rather odd names, though, you could have done all this much more briefly and clearly, like this:

```
var err : NSError?
if let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, 
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
        _dictionary = dico.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]
    } else {
        println(err)
    }
```

Moreover, if you start with the String class instead of the NSString class, then `componentsSeparatedByString` will be an array of String instead of an untyped NSArray (i.e. an array of AnyObject), and you can skip the cast:

```
var err : NSError?
if let dico = String(contentsOfFile: path!, 
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
        _dictionary = dico.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    } else {
        println(err)
    }
```

Comment: One should cast it to [String] because then the values can be provided to functions that demand Strings without fuss. Unless there's some remarkable performance drawback I don't know about.

Comment: Of course. But there was no need to use `as?`. He could have done it with `as` and avoided one extra level of optional wrapping and unwrapping.

Comment: I should have mentioned the reasoning for naming it a dictionary, it's actually a dictionary of English words. I'm working my way through your answer and hopefully can clean that code up and understand it better. Feel free to illustrate the proper way to do it with the init.

Comment: @Half_Duplex Just move the code into an initializer. But you must _still_ supply a value in case reading the file fails.

Comment: @Half_Duplex Did I answer the right questions? If there's anything left unclear, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @matt Yeah I think you got me on the right track... I was able to factor the code down to what was needed:
`var err: NSError?`
`let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)`
`let dictionary = dico?.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]`

I'll rename dictionary, in Java it's just another word. Going to use your advice and move it all into a constructor

Comment: @matt just to make sure I'm clear I have to cast the array returned by `componentsSeparatedByString` because it's obj-c and returns an untyped array.

Comment: Yes, only because you started with NSString. If you had said `String(contents...`, then `components` would be a `[String]` and you can skip the cast. I'm going to add that to my answer!